# Connect to remote phpMyAdmin

Tags: java, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to connect to a remote mysql server which is in phpMyAdmin through jdbc. I am not able to access the server.I am entering IP address and port no in my connection String.Is it possible to know the IP address and port no for the mysql server.Since i am not sure if the entered IP address and port no are correct.

I want to find the connection string of that database, in order to be able to communicate with my database using java.

Does anyone knows how to find that connection string?

Comment: Is there an error message? You should also check, if your user has the permission to connect from a remote host. If you rent some webspace anywhere it is typically not possible to remotly connect to your database.
Maybe first try to use MySQL Workbench or DBVisualizer to connect. I think they will both give you a valid JDBC url if the connection works.

Comment: I wonder what PHPMyAdmin has to do with this question? Its just a PHP management web interface, its not like without it MySQL cannot be reached.

Comment: @Gimmy ya you are correct but i am getting access denied error when trying to connect to the server.

Comment: if you're getting access denied through jdbc then probably one of your parameters is wrong, either the password, username, database name, or the url. is this remote database hosted through a provider, or another machine on your network?